# how to convert SQL query to raw query

Tags: laravel

```
SELECT fp.id, fp.name, fp.slug, fp.status, fc.name, fc.slug as category_slug, fp.approved, ff.filepath, fdp.product_id,fdp.type, fdp.sku, fdp.regular_price, fdp.sale_price, fp.created_at, fp.updated_at 
FROM `foduu_products` fp 
       JOIN `foduu_details_product` fdp ON fp.id= fdp.product_id 
       JOIN `foduu_category_product` fcp ON fp.id = fcp.product_id
       JOIN `foduu_filemanager` ff ON fp.filemanager_id = ff.id
       JOIN `foduu_categories` fc ON fcp.category_id = fc.id
WHERE fc.slug= "microsoftheadphonesadaptersmotherboardswebcam" 
      AND fp.approved = 1 
      AND fp.status = 1
```

Comment: I think that query is as raw as it gets

Comment: but this query not work propar

Comment: i should DB::table('foduu_products as fp' ) formet

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're not going to do it for you unless we see that you have already made an honest effort and are just having difficulty

Comment: ok thanks sir, i will try

Answer (score 0):

This code should work according to your logic:

```
  $match = ['fc.slug' => 'microsoftheadphonesadaptersmotherboardswebcam', 'fp.approved' => '1', 'fp.status'=>'1'];

    $result = DB::table('foduu_products as fd')
                 ->join('foduu_details_product as fdp','fp.id','=','fdp.product_id')
                 ->join(......
                        .............
                 ->where($match)
                 ->select('fp.id', 'fp.name', ...................)
                 ->get();
```